# Writing Javascript code to HTTP response from Controller

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

In a Struts application some controllers write Javascript code to the HTTP response (this JS code will be executed when the submit ends). Do you think it's a bad approach or is acceptable ? Would it be better to set an attribute and move the JS code to the view ?

```
@UserInterfaceEvent
public void aceptar_onClick(FormActionContext ctx) {

    IGenerateDocListOutputBF bproxy = ProxyFactory.newBusinessProxy(getBusinessComponent(), IGenerateDocListOutputBF.class);

    GenerateDocListOutputForm form = (GenerateDocListOutputForm) ctx.form();
    String mode = form.getDetailMode();
    removeErrors(ctx);

    GemaBrowseControl browse = (GemaBrowseControl) ctx.session().getAttribute("outputs");
    SelectedData data = browse.getAllSelectedData(ctx, true);

    try {
        bproxy.generateOutputs(data.getSelectedDboids(), form.getDboid(), false);
        if (GemaAppErrorMgr.currentScopeHasErrors()) {
            ctx.request().setAttribute(DetailRequest.MODE, mode);
            showErrorPopUp(ctx);
        } else {
            String javascript = "<script>window.opener.refreshDivDocsRelated(); window.close();</script>";          
            ctx.response().getOutputStream().print(javascript);
            ctx.forwardToResponse();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e, ctx.request());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On my opinion it is extremely bad practice. Mixing the business logic and representation layers will not only make it harder to understand (what if the back-end dev does not understand JS at all?), but event more importantly it will make it harder to debug, especially in big projects where the people are constantly changing and this knowledge is lost in process.

I would implement an AJAX call and execute that JS upon request completion (on the view side ofc).

Comment: Yes it could be done with an Ajax call but needs a lot of refactoring (it's an old app).